# Segmentation Error on Server

Tags: c++

i get an segmentation error on the server and i can't find the problem.

It's the university server where i can only compile, but not debug.

I only get a Segmentation fault (core dumped)
sometimes it's working sometimes not

on windows 10 it's always working.
we had to compile it with on the server:

```
/opt/global/gcc-5.2.0/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/global/gcc-5.2.0/lib64 HelloThread.cpp -lpthread
```

This is my main class, I'm confused because on windows it's working pretty well!
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;
//global variables because of quick and dirty...

vector<float> x = {-10.2, -8.0, 0.5, 5.9, 3.5, 22.7, 15.0, -1.8, -3.1, 7.7, 11.2, 7.9, -3.3,
                   -1.6, 15.3, 22.6, 3.6, 5.7, 2.0, -18.2, -27.5, 23.1, 18.1, 9.7, 25.8};
float mf=0;
float sf=0;
vector<float> z;
float oDN=0; //oDN= one divided by N
atomic<int> getXMf(0);
atomic<int> getXSf(0);
atomic<int> getXZ(0);

void calcMf() {
    for (getXMf; getXMf < x.size(); getXMf++) {
        mf += oDN * x[getXMf];
    }
}

void calcSf() {
    for (getXSf; getXSf < x.size(); getXSf++) {
        sf += oDN * (fabsf(x[getXSf] - mf));
    }
}

void calcZ() {
    for (getXZ; getXZ < x.size(); getXZ++) {
        z.insert(z.begin() + getXZ, (x[getXZ] - mf) / sf);
    }
}

int main() {
    //initial args
    thread getSizeOfMaxThreads;
    vector<thread> worker1;
    vector<thread> worker2;
    vector<thread> worker3;
    int maxThreadSize =getSizeOfMaxThreads.hardware_concurrency();
    float getSizeofX = x.size();
    oDN = 1 / getSizeofX;
    //
    //first worker doing calcMF and pushing to a vector
    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreadSize; ++i) {
        worker1.push_back(thread(&calcMf)
        );
    }
    //call first threads and join em;
    for_each(worker1.begin(), worker1.end(), [](thread &th) { // Collective Join
        th.join();
    });

    //second worker doing calcMF and pushing to a vector
    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreadSize; ++i) {
        worker2.push_back(thread(&calcSf)
        );
    }
    //call second threads and join em;
    for_each(worker2.begin(), worker2.end(), [](thread &th) { // Collective Join
        th.join();
    });

    //third worker doing calcMF and pushing to a vector
    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreadSize; ++i) {
        worker3.push_back(thread(&calcZ)
        );
    }
    //call third threads and join em;
    for_each(worker3.begin(), worker3.end(), [](thread &th) { // Collective Join
        th.join();
    });
    cout << "mf: " << mf << endl;
    cout << "sf: " << sf << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "this is z[" << i << "]: " << z[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: we  are not allowed to use any libraries

Comment: Using an `atomic<int>` **in no way** makes the for-loops thread safe. Between testing against `size()` and using the index, the other threads could easily increment the index (several times).

Comment: ok thank you so i should use, mutex?!

Comment: As you were told in your other question, you have race conditions. This `z.insert(z.begin() + getXZ, (x[getXZ] - mf) / sf);`is new and makes your program crash.

Comment: @manni66, i fixed the old one, created a thread variable, because" vector myThread[0] was empty. so first i have to put  something in "z"  and after that it's possible to insert something because "z" is empy like null? please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: _i fixed the old one_ no, you didn't. _i have to put something in "z" and after that it's possible to insert something_ no, you can't insert into a vector without protecting it with a mutex. And if you protect it with a mutex you will serialize your threads. You can resize z and assign like I did in my answer.

Comment: @manni66
I mean this one `thread getSizeOfMaxThreads;`, `int maxThreadSize =getSizeOfMaxThreads.hardware_concurrency();` or did i something wrong?

Comment: And that's a race condition?

Comment: I mean in the other question, what you mentioned.
I tried to fix the race condition with atomic, so the getXMf variable is only increased one by one  and access the vector only once at the getXMf position.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is broken. The reason is the wrong level of abstraction. You should use a library like TBB, that raises the level of abstraction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>

#include <tbb/tbb.h>

using namespace std;
//global variables because of quick and dirty...

template <typename Iter, typename T, typename Func>
T AssocReduce( Iter first, Iter last, T identity, Func calc ) {
  return tbb::parallel_reduce(
                  // Index range for reduction
                  tbb::blocked_range<Iter>(first,last),
                  // Identity element
                  identity,
                  // Reduce a subrange and partial sum
                  [&]( tbb::blocked_range<Iter> r, T partial_sum )->float {
                return std::accumulate( r.begin(), r.end(), partial_sum, calc );
                  },
                  // Reduce two partial sums
                  std::plus<T>()
                  );
}

vector<float> x = {-10.2, -8.0, 0.5, 5.9, 3.5, 22.7, 15.0, -1.8, -3.1, 7.7, 11.2, 7.9, -3.3,
                   -1.6, 15.3, 22.6, 3.6, 5.7, 2.0, -18.2, -27.5, 23.1, 18.1, 9.7, 25.8};
float mf=0;
float sf=0;
vector<float> z;
float oDN= 1.0 / x.size();

int main() {
  auto Mf = []( float sum, float val ) {
    return sum + ( oDN * val );
  };

  mf = AssocReduce( begin(x), end(x), 0.0f, Mf );

  auto Sf = []( float sum, float val ) {
    return sum + ( oDN *  (fabsf(val - mf) ) );
  };

  sf = AssocReduce( begin(x), end(x), 0.0f, Sf );

  z.resize(x.size());

  tbb::parallel_for( size_t{}, x.size(), [](int i) {
      z[i] = (x[i] - mf) / sf;
    });

  cout << "mf: " << mf << endl;
  cout << "sf: " << sf << endl;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "this is z[" << i << "]: " << z[i] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but we are not allowed to use any libraries